# Making a spring boot app to load data from an existing oracle database?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, spring-boot, oracle11g

I've created a spring boot app to load data from an existing distant oracle database. I succeeded to have a communication into the DB with the settings in my `application.properties`.
So my next step is how can I automatically generate my entites, and then get data? 
For this I've tried to connect with the Intellij UI but had many problems (Unable to apply SSH settings: Host & port not found)

The main reason why I'm looking to do this by using a java app is that I have many blob data that I need to get.

Any idea ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I agree the best option is to make IntelliJ to generate entities for you and then hand engineer where required. If they are not too much you can hand engineer by yourself as the best option available.

In addition you can try with hibernate3-maven-plugin, I found that link to be useful http://www.celinio.net/techblog/?p=1125

Answer (score 0):

You can use `schema.sql` or `data.sql` in resource directory, these will get execute at the start of the application.

Comment: I'm not looking for executing sql file, but getting the java entity equivalent